# How do I get a `callFrameID` to pass to `Debugger.evaluateOnCallFrame`?

Tags: remote-debugging, google-chrome-devtools

WebKit's Remote Debugging Protocol went 1.0 recently and I've been playing around with it a little, mostly out of curiosity and interest. I've thrown together a very basic recreation of Chrome's developer tools console as a replacement front-end, but I'm a little confused as to how I can execute code in a specific frame/window like Chrome's Dev Tools allow you to.

At the moment, I'm using the `Runtime.evaluate` method to execute my console input. This seems inadequate because of the aforementioned problem and it doesn't provide the command line API. I've discovered the [*Debugger.evaluateOnCallFrame* method](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/tot/debugger#command-evaluateOnCallFrame), which requires a `callFrameID` parameter. The only problem is, it doesn't seem possible to remotely acquire a list of `callFrame` objects to pass to this method.

I have a feeling I'm completely missing something here. Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Debugger.paused](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/tot/debugger#event-paused) event, which will give you an array of current call frames.

Comment: Doesn't this only trigger when the debugger is paused? I haven't had this notification through yet the entire time I've been playing around with it.

Comment: Hmm... what do you think CallFrames are? :)

Comment: I thought a CallFrame was a representation of a JavaScript environment, and each window had its own. I guess I'm confused on that too?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, thinking that "frame" meant "stackframe". A callframe is a synonym for a stackframe. Once the debugger pauses (due to an exception or a breakpoint), it will provide you with a list of current callframes. You can evaluate expressions in a context of any of those (e.g. `this` and local variables will evaluate to different values in different frame contexts.) What you refer as "a JavaScript environment" is essentially used by `Runtime.evaluate`. What you are looking for, is done by `WebInspector.JavaScriptContextManager` (look up the Web Inspector source).

Comment: In fact, [Inspector.json](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/Inspector.json) describes the entire protocol, but the `Runtime.evaluate` parameters you need are marked as "hidden" (which means they don't get into the API docs.) Try using the hidden `frameId` parameter to this method.

Comment: *sigh*, I did look through that file but I was obviously looking in the wrong place.  Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: The "hidden" stuff is somewhat experimental and may break/change/vanish in future, so use it with caution and do no rely on it in your production code. Same thing holds for the `Runtime.evaluate` signature - it might use some improvement, hence the tail parameters are hidden.